# DDD - How to reuse code in Application layer?

Tags: domain-driven-design

How to reuse code in an application layer without mapping?

Let's have an application service OrderService with AddOrder(OrderDto) method.
The method is used by rest api. A controller method calls OrderService.AddOrder(OrderDto) and it maps the OrderDto param to the Order entity. The Order entity is then added to a repository. The mapping is done there because OrderService and AddOrder is an application interface.

It would be nice to reuse the code and call OrderService.AddOrder(orderDto) not just from the controller but also from another method in OrderService or even from another application service.

However, it always needs mapping from an entity to DTO inside the application service method before calling another application method and then mapping the result back from DTO to entity.

=> Useless mapping in the same layer. With the system going bigger it ends up with mapping from and to DTO everywhere. BAD.

It would be good to avoid the mapping inside and do it only on the top of the application interface.
We could write a service accepting an domain model (entity) instead of DTO in the params: OrderDomainService.AddOrder(order).

This resolves the "mapping problem". Domain services can call each other without mapping and Application services can also call the domain services. However, it means a domain service has to use a repository from Infrastructure layer to load data because we moved the code from an application service method to the domain service method. This creates a dependency from Domain layer to Infrastructure layer.

=> Wrong dependency. Infrastructure should depend on Domain, not Domain on Inrastructure.

How to resolve that?

The application service shouldn't contains methods with params of domain model types.
The domain service can't use repository.

Where to write the reusable code then?

Or I'm wrong and the domain service can use the repository. Via an interface in Domain layer it wouldn't be dependent directly on the infrastructure layer.
However then it would end up with a controller method calling an application service method calling an domain service method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track moving towards ***domain services*** when it comes to reusing logic. Application services are suited for orchestrating specific use cases and only call different actions in the correct order. Domain logic should always be in the domain layer.

Concerning the infrastructure dependency: for using repositories in DDD (or clean architecture) the ***repository interfaces*** should reside in the *domain layer* while the concrete *implementation* of these interfaces reside in the *infrastructure layer*.

Both the application layer and the domain layer should depend on the interfaces rather than the infrastructure layer then.

> The domain service can't use repository.

So it *can* use a repository by being dependent on the repository interface while the concrete infrastructure repository is injected at runtime following dependency injection.

> However then it would end up with a controller method calling an application service method calling an domain service method.

If there is no justification for an application service as there is no real orchestration required you at least don't break any dependency rules when letting a controller call domain classes directly, e.g. if the use case is too simply and no abstraction between the API layer (here a controller) and the domain layer is needed. But I usually rather like to use Application services as they make the domain layer independent from this outer layer and allow both, the domain layer and the API layer to evolve independently from each other.

Comment: If the domain service can use an infrastructure code (via an interface in the domain layer), so it can use the repositories, it can then be used as an orchestrator instead of the application service method.
It can work so that the app can consist mainly of code in domain services and if a domain service method should be exposed out of the app, it can be "wrapped" by the application service method containing the mapping code.
That would be great from a practical point of view but is that right that the orchestration logic would be in the domain service method where a business logic should be?

Comment: As I stated in my answer ***Application services*** are suited for orchestrating specific use cases. Domain services and domain model classes contain business domain logic. Application services orchestrate things like mapping DTOs (e.g. commands) to domain model representations, retrieving domain entities from repositories, calling a specific (or more) methods on aggregates or domain services and telling the repository again to store the changed aggregate. This should not happen in a domain service.

Comment: For a better understanding of *application services* vs. *domain services* you can take a look at this blog: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-vs-application-services/#:~:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20them,whereas%20application%20services%20don't.&text=And%20application%20services%20orchestrate%20those,by%20entities%20and%20value%20objects.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read it though I have idea how it works.

I'm wondering how to reuse the application service code = the orchestration code and how to avoid the mapping from entity to dto and vice versa when the application service methods are called between each other because that seems to be useles to do it in the same layer. Is it not possible in DDD if I can't use the domain service then?

Comment: DDD only gives strategical patterns (ubiquituous language, bounded contexts, etc.) and tactical patterns (aggregates, repositories, domain services, etc.) that you can apply if it fits your needs. There are no rules that keep you from arranging your application services in a way that you can reuse code. I would suggest you implement this the way that best fits your needs by mainly focusing on not to introduce any direct infrastructure dependencies into your services.

Comment: In many times you need to try it out and see the code first. Then you can decide if this common code you have in mind would rather be part of an extracted domain service or really just some shared component in the application layer which several application services should be able to reuse.

Comment: An example can be a rest api assigning a tag to a product. The tag can be found by id or by name but the rest would be the same. TagService would have two methods AddTagToProduct(tagId) and AddTagToProduct(tagName). The code inside would be the same with a difference in getting the tag from repository. Another example can be an integration service calling other application services. Or CustomerService creating a customer with steps in other services. For example adding it to departments etc.

Comment: You can take a look at Vaughn Vernon's DDD samples. In this application services he simply has a private method (*startNewForum()*) used in several use cases, see https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/forum/ForumApplicationService.java